# Why doesn't this function always return the longest palindromic substring in a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this solution to a codewars problem (https://www.codewars.com/kata/longest-palindrome). It passes all but one of the tests, in which it returns 2 instead of 7.

Why might this solution fail?

def longest_palindrome (s):

```
if s == '':
    return 0
if len(s) == 1:
    return 1 

palindrome_lengths = []

for i in range(len(s)):

    # determine all indices for the character
    indices = []
    for p, character in enumerate(s):
        if character == s[i]:
            indices.append(p)

    # check if each substring is a palindrome and, if so, add length to palindrome_lengths
    index = 1
    while index < len(indices):      

        # grab the substring
        substring = s[indices[0]:indices[index]+1]

        # reverse the substring
        reverse_substring = substring[::-1]

        # if forward substring equals reverse, add length to a list of lengths
        if substring == reverse_substring:
            palindrome_lengths.append(len(substring))

        index += 1

if palindrome_lengths == []:
    return 1
else:
    palindrome_lengths.sort(reverse=True)
    return palindrome_lengths[0]
```

Comment: When you test it with a debugger, where does it *first* behave differently than you expected?

Comment: What part of this code is *supposed* to identify the longest palindrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never check any substring that doesn't start with the first occurrence of its first letter in the original string (for example, for the string `"mamadam"`, you never test the substring starting with the second `m`).